# How do I get the number of likes on a tweet via tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a tweepy tweet object and I can see and print its `favorite_count` and `retweet_count` but I do not see a `like_count` when I print the member variables of the object. Knowing the number of favorites seems a lot less relevant for typical use cases of working with a tweet as it is far more common to like something on Twitter than to favorite it.

I am able to do something like this:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
print(tweet.retweet_count)
print(tweet.favorite_count)
```

but doing

```
print(tweet.like_count)
```

Does not work and I can't see any alternative. Furthermore when I google things like "tweepy get like count of a tweet" nothing relevant pops up which just seems odd. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Favourites are the same as likes. There is no difference. Clicking on a heart on Twitter increments the favourite count.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/hearts-and-likes-are-live/55642

Comment: how odd as the favorite counts are not correct, in that they do not appear the same as the like count when i view tweets on the twitter website. retweet values are correct though.

Comment: favourites_count is not the like count of a post. It's the number of likes user has received collectively.